# Error calling the lapack-based Armadillo function svd - receive 'Intel MKL Error'

Tags: c++, intel, mex, lapack, armadillo

I have been using Armadillo recently to write c++ mex files to speed up some Matlab code. So far, I have really only been using the 'cube' and 'matrix' data storage types and straightforward operations.

I am interested in computing the SVD armadillo function. However, when I am calling the svd function, Matlab reports 'warning: svd(): decomposition failed'.

Additionally, the command window will report "Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 12 was incorrect on entry to DGESDD". DGESDD is from the Lapack library and performs the SVD, which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong with connecting the Armadillo and Lapack libraries.

Does anyone know how to correct this problem?

In Matlab, I initialize the function as:
mex -v testFunction.cpp -larmadillo -lblas -llapack

In the mex file, I am currently using the exact example from the Armadillo website for svd:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include "armaMex.hpp"
#include <omp.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

... general mex function calls ...

mat X = randu<mat>(5,5);

mat U;
vec s;
mat V;

svd(U,s,V,X);
```

Comment: Does Matlab let you single-step your C in a debugger to find out where that error message is coming from?  According to what I found (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html#d119e19504) calls from Matlab into your C++ source go through a function that returns `void`, so it's not that you're returning garbage that's treated as a "false" success code.

Comment: You should show the function that contains those C++ statements, because they can't be at global scope.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am not sure where the DGESDD function is specifically called. It should be called in the svd function from the armadillo library, which I call as shown above - the same as it is written in the example code.

Comment: Try removing <omp.h> and <lapacke.h>, don't think you need to include them judging from your code extract.

Comment: @ClaesRolen I did try that, but I am still receiving the error message

Comment: It may be the link order, try to include it like -lblas -llapack -larmadillo